# Jquery drag drop hangs or stuck in android browser due to touch event

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, google-chrome

when i drag drop object from both end it gets stucked somewhere where as when i click somewhere on screen it starts working i think it may be due to mouse event and touch event conflict .

i am using "jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js" js for mobile event 
some time it works and sometime  i get stuck problem. this problem occurs only in chromium works fine in chrome browser.

how can i solve this , any event to update mouse and touch event form whole dom or i might be missing something

see link below :http://liveweave.com/JckSgC

Comment: create test case in liveweave with your current source

Comment: You can place your working source: Html, CSS and JavaScript in respective sections, you can use jsfiddle.net as well